# WP - jQuery does not work on homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using `jQuery.noConflict();` and it's just before the **wp_footer**. It works on the other sections, it's not about the code 'cause not even the `alert();` seems to work.

What could it be?

Comment: check using firebug if jQuery is properly loading or not.

Comment: found the bug.... I should've gone to firebug before posting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Check you've included jQuery on your page, and the path to it is correct.

2) I assume from your mention of wp_footer, you've put `noConflict()` at the end of the document. Try placing it in the `head` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't jQuery default included by Wordpress now? You may be adding different versions than the stock.